# WordPress Custom Taxonomy hierarchical terms rewrite

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy URL structure that is as follows:

/term_slug/post_name

I have created custom rewrite rules to do this, as follows:

```
register_taxonomy( 'blog_type', 'post', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Blog Types', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Blog Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Blog Types' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Blog Types' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Blog Type' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Blog Type:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Blog Type' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Blog Type' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Blog Type' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Blog Type Name' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Blog Type' ),
        ),
        'rewrite' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    ) );

    add_rewrite_tag( "%blog_type%", '(.+?)', "blog_type=" );


    // Get all the blog types
    $blog_types = get_terms( 'blog_type', array( 'hide_empty' => false, ) );

    if( ! empty( $blog_types ) ) {
        foreach( $blog_types as $blog_type ) {
            add_rewrite_rule( "$blog_type->slug/?$", "index.php?post_type=post&taxonomy=blog_type&term=$blog_type->slug", 'top' );
            add_rewrite_rule( "$blog_type->slug/{$wp_rewrite->pagination_base}/([0-9]{1,})/?$", "index.php?post_type=post&taxonomy=blog_type&term=$blog_type->slug&paged=$matches[1]", 'top' );

            add_permastruct( "%$blog_type->slug%", "$blog_type->slug/%postname%", false );
        }
    }
```

This works fine and dandy, except I need to include sub-terms in the URL structure as well, so for example:

/term_slug/term_subterm_slug/post_name

This would include multiple-dimensional taxonomies in which terms have sub-terms. I am a bit stuck at the moment, any help?

I have looked at [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types) but it does not elaborate on how to create the URL structure with a dynamic amount of sub-terms.

Comment: This will help you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/mixing-custom-post-type-and-taxonomy-rewrite-structures

Comment: The answers on [How to enable hierarchical permalinks for hierarchical taxonomies](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/17325/5871) might help.